# How do I add a condition to an existing conditional expression?

Tags: perl

I had a programmer write a Perl script for my site.

One of the functions is to update price/stock when a certain condition is met.

```
# update when price/stock conditions met
if ( ($force_price_updates == 1) || 
     ($data->{'price'} <= $product_price && $data->{'quantity'} > 0) ||
     ($product_quantity == 0 && $data->{'quantity'} > 0) ) {
```

What the above is not doing is not updating the price if the new price is higher. It updates the stock value, but if the new stock comes at a higher price, I lose out. Stock gets updated and but the price is not.

The script goes through a number of feeds and if the same product is found in any of the feeds, the script should amend price/stock change according to the rule above.

I can't find the programmer and my Perl knowledge is limited. I understand what the code is doing, but don't know what it should do if the price is higher and stock is greater than zero.

Comment: Which one is the new price? `$data->{price}` or `$product_price`?

Comment: $data->{price} is the new price

Comment: consider adding line breaks to make it more readable! it's really hard to see the precedence of operators there when it's all in one big line

Answer (score 1):

You can add the extra condition you're looking for to that statement.

The condition you're looking to match is:

```
$data->{'price'} > $product_price && $product_quantity > 0
```

So the final version would look like this:

```
if (($force_price_updates == 1) || ($data->{'price'} <= $product_price && $data->{'quantity'} > 0) || ($product_quantity == 0 && $data->{'quantity'} > 0) || ($data->{'price'} > $product_price && $product_quantity > 0)) {
```